# onsenUIを使ったWebサイトを作成する際、ページごとにファイルを分割したい

Tags: onsen-ui

はじめまして。

onsenUIを使用してWebページを作成しています。
monacaでの開発の際には、ons-navigatorを使用してindex.htmlとは別のファイルを作成してpushPage()等できたのですが、Webページでは以下のエラーが出てしまい、動作しません。

=====

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///xxxx/xxx/xxxx/test/start.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Uncaught Error: The page is not found: start.html
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (internal.js:151)
    at internal.js:153
    at setImmediate.js:48
    at runIfPresent (setImmediate.js:67)
    at onGlobalMessage (setImmediate.js:113)

=====

以下にソースを添付します。

=====

・index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="lib/OnsenUI2.4.0/js/onsenui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/OnsenUI2.4.0/css/onsenui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/OnsenUI2.4.0/css/onsen-css-components.css" />
  </head>
  <body id="index">
    <ons-navigator animation="fade" id="testNavigator" page="start.html" refresh="true"></ons-navigator>
  </body>
</html>
```

・start.html

```
<ons-page id="start-page">
  ここは start.html です。
</ons-page>
```

=====

使用しているonsenUIのバージョンは、2.4.0、
検証しているブラウザはchromeです。

全てindex.htmlにまとめてしまえば動くのですが、管理が乱雑になってしまい困っています。

解決策をご存知でしたら、ご教授頂けますでしょうか？
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///xxxx/xxx/xxxx/test/start.html.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Chromeでのエラーに関してはAjaxで非同期にローカルファイルを読み込むことができないという[Chromeの制限](http://dev.classmethod.jp/etc/chrome-localfile-security/)のようです。
オプション指定やsudo権限でChrome起動すれば制限を受けないという記述を見つけましたが、おそらくやりたいことの根本解決ではないでしょう。

navigaterによるルーティング制御はSPAを想定されたものです。
そのため$templateCacheを利用して事前にテンプレートを読み込んでおくことで対処できるかと思います。

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('start.html', '<ons-page id="start-page">ここは start.html です。</ons-page>');
});
```

[onsen-uiのページ定義](https://ja.onsen.io/v2/docs/guide/angular1/index.html#template)や[$templateCacheのドキュメント](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache)も参考にしてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
やはりフレームワークが必要になるのですね。

遅くなりましたが、試してみます。
ありがとうございました！